# Getting the types of method overloads with CRTP

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have been thinking, whether it is possible with C++20, to somehow get the types of method overloads to a tuple:

```
template<typename CRTP>
struct Template {
    // ERROR! But how to make it work? Some metaprogramming magic?
    static inline constexpr std::tuple t{&CRTP::f...};
};

struct S : Template<S> {
    void f(int) { }
    void f(bool) { }
};
```

I would like the tuple to effectively contain: `&S::f(int), &S::f(bool)`.

EDIT: The idea is to be able to have multiple, various classes that can utilize the Template:

```
struct S1 : Template<S> {
    void f(int) { }
    void f(bool) { }
};

struct S2 : Template<S> {
    void f(std::string) { }
    void f(double) { }
    void f(std::vector<unsigned>) {}
    void f(SomeOtherType) {}
};
```

Comment: No, there is no reflection in C++.

Comment: CRTP would be the wrong way: within CRTP, the "derived type" is **incomplete**. A regular traits would be the way.

Comment: Can't you use something like `struct S1 : Template<int, bool> {/*..*/};`?

Comment: The tuple would be of infinite size if `f` is a template function

Comment: @Jarod42 I guess even with regular traits it would be impossible to find all the S::f() overloads, and put them to the tuple, without explicitly specifying the types of the parameters?

Comment: @Jarod42 The solution `struct S1 : Template<int, bool> { /* ... */ }; would be the one I would go for from the beginning. I wrote this question to find out whether I could somehow deduce those types automagically.

Answer (score 0):

If you need some sort of reflection - to find **all** methods with a given name then no, there is not (yet) reflection on C++. You could possibly add one pass to the compiler [as described here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) but that is not part of the language.

That said, you can build *a priori* tables that you can query later, as in the example below.

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<typename CRTP>
struct Template {
    typedef void (CRTP::*IntFn)(int);
    typedef void (CRTP::*BoolFn)(bool);
    static inline constexpr std::tuple<IntFn,BoolFn> t{&CRTP::f,&CRTP::f};
};

struct S : Template<S> {
    void f(int i) { std::cout << "int " << i << std::endl; }
    void f(bool b) { std::cout << "bool " << (b?"true":"false") << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    (s.*std::get<0>(S::t))(1);
    (s.*std::get<1>(S::t))(1);
}
```

Produces

```
Program stdout
int 1
bool true
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Gbjj6Y7KK

Comment: Thanks, but not really. I have edited the question to be more specific.